# Better way to create a delay of 2 seconds after each http request in Swift

Tags: swift

I use the following code to make http requests.

```
    for marca in marcasFiltradasPorParteAnimalCombinadaComDescricaoDeTodasPartesPorTipo {
            
            self.myUploadGroupMarcas.enter()
            do { sleep(2) }
                            
            let jsonRequestUploadImagemGrafica = JsonHelper.createJsonMarcaResenha(marca, resenhaDados.IdGedave )
            
            let json: [String: Any] = jsonRequestUploadImagemGrafica
            guard let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json) else {
                printLog("guard jsonData error 3")
                return
            }
                            
            let networkManager = NetworkManager()
            networkManager.post(endpoint: Constantes.Endpoint.upload_marca, data: jsonData) { [weak self] result in
                printDebug("dentro do post: \(result)")
                guard let self = self else { return }
                switch result {
                case .success(let data):
                    printDebug("Received data: \(data.toUtf8())")
                    self.tratarRespostaUploadMarca(data: data, marca: marca)
                    self.myUploadGroupMarcas.leave()
                case .failure(let error):
                    printDebug("Error: \(error)")
                    self.myUploadGroupMarcas.leave()
                }
                
            }
                            
        }
    
        myUploadGroupMarcas.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] in
            printDebug("___ myUploadGroupMarcas notify marcas enviadas")
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.liberarResenha()
        }
```

I use the "sleep" code to create a delay between each request because the server need some time to process each request. The "networkManager.post" uses a URLSession to send a http request, but I don't know if the "sleep" stop only the main thread or if stops dataTask from the URLSession(from networkManager.post) to finish it's job.

Question 1 - I suppose the dataTask is a background thread and is not affected by the sleep code. Is that correct?

Question 2 - There is a better way to create a delay of 2 seconds between each request without using sleep ?

--- EDIT ---

This is my Network Manager class

```
enum NetworkError: Error {
 case invalidURL
 case invalidResponse
 case noData
 case dataConversionInvalid
 case requestFailed
}

class NetworkManager {

let baseURL: String

let maxCharactersOnCurlString: Int = 1200

init() {
    self.baseURL = Ambiente.pegaUrlAmbiente()
}

func post(endpoint: String, data: Data, completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    
    printDebug("NetworkManaget post start")
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "\(baseURL)\(endpoint)") else {
        completion(.failure(NetworkError.invalidURL))
        return
    }
            
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = data
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("\(String(describing: data.count))", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    let base64LoginString = EndpointController.getBase64StringLoginWithUserAndPasswordV2()
    request.addValue(base64LoginString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    printDebug("request post curl")
    printDebug(request)
    printDebug(request.curlString.prefix(maxCharactersOnCurlString)) // apresenta erro ao enviar imagem
    
    let myUrlSession = URLSessionHelper.getUrlSessionByUrlAddress()
    let task = myUrlSession.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }
        
        printDebug("response post")
        printDebug(response)
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200..<300).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            //completion(.failure(NetworkError.requestFailed))
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(.failure(NetworkError.noData))
                return
            }
            
            let dataErrorString: String = String(data: data, encoding: .isoLatin1) ?? "Erro conversão string data"
            printDebug("dataErrorString: \(dataErrorString)")
            let myError = NSError(domain: "httpRequest",
                                  code: (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? -1,
                                  userInfo: [ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: dataErrorString]
            )
            completion(.failure(myError))
            return
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            completion(.failure(NetworkError.noData))
            return
        }
        
        completion(.success(data))
    }
    
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Watch “Meet async await”